# Find number after a substring in string

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, python-2.7

Want to have function that can find a number after a substring in a string, e.g.:

```
>>> find_number('abc123de34','e')
34
>>> find_number('abc123de34','de')
34
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: What's your *current* way to do it, and why do you think it could be improved? You've tagged this [tag:regex], so did you try writing a regular expression?

Comment: `'abc123de34'['abc123de34'.index('e'):]`, `'abc123de34'['abc123de34'.index('de'):]` assuming substring exists.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Regex**: `char(\d+)`

Details:

- `\d` Matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times
- `()` Capturing group

**Python code**:

String formatting syntax `"%s" % var`.The `%s` token allows to insert (and potentially format) a string.

```
def find_number(text, c):
    return re.findall(r'%s(\d+)' % c, text)

find_number('abce123de34', 'e') >> ['123', '34']
find_number('abce123de34', 'de') >> ['34']
```

Comment: Specifically with a pandas dataframe I used the formula above and applied it with a lambda function to create a new column. dataset['new column'] = dataset.apply(lambda x: find_number(x['your column with the string you are searching for'], 'text'), axis=1)

Answer (score 1):

The following program works. But it can be improved a lot.

```
def func(string, sub):
    subpos = string.find(sub)
    new_string = string[subpos + 1:]
    for x in new_string:
        try:
            int(x)
        except:
            endpos = new_string.find(x)
            break

    num = string[subpos + 1:subpos + endpos + 1]
    return num

string = 'abc12de34fg'
sub = 'e'
num = func(string, sub)
print(num)
```